# is there a way to detect pictures in images?

Tags: opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, computer-science, object-recognition

I want to know if there is a way to detect pictures in images. For example, the task is to recognize an apple and a photo of an apple in given image. Is it possible with OpenCV or any other way?

Comment: are you searching for some specific pictures or generally for any pictures? What kind of images does your application expect to see?

Answer (score 0):

I don't thing this could be done using only opencv. You should look in to a deep learning approach. There are many models trained for object detection. eg:- YOLO model

Comment: Opencv does have a DNN module and you can use it to train models, although I agree that eating a bag of rusty nails would be more pleasant.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it will be helpful:

```
import glob
from PIL import Image

def transparent(myimage):
    img = Image.open(myimage)
    img = img.convert("RGBA")

    pixdata = img.load()

    width, height = img.size
    for y in range(height):
        for x in range(width):
            if pixdata[x, y] == (0, 0, 0, 255):
                print(True)
            else:
                print(False)


img.save(myimage, "PNG")

for image in glob.glob("*.png"):
    transparent('mypic.png')
```

this actually is not that useful, but changing this:

```
if pixdata[x, y] == (0, 0, 0, 255):
    print(True)
else:
    print(False)
```

will change the color you check for, and what you do with it.

This code is able to check the color. I wish it help.